# Is it good or bad configuration

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cooling

I already two times this system is burned .BIOS was re setted . and the system engineer told that better to change mother board.
please help me really i need to change my mother board?

```
Open Hardware Monitor Report

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version: 0.7.1.0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Common Language Runtime: 4.0.30319.296
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0
Process Type: 64-Bit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sensors

|
+- Guso G4x 775 + ICH6 Series (/mainboard)
|  |
|  +- Winbond W83627DHG-P (/lpc/w83627dhgp)
|  |  +- CPU VCore      :     1.12    1.112     1.12 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/0)
|  |  +- Voltage #2     :     1.04    1.032    1.048 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/1)
|  |  +- AVCC           :    3.536     3.52    3.584 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/2)
|  |  +- 3VCC           :    3.552     3.52    3.584 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/3)
|  |  +- Voltage #5     :     1.48     1.48    1.488 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/4)
|  |  +- Voltage #6     :    1.952    1.944    1.968 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/5)
|  |  +- Voltage #7     :    1.912    1.912    1.912 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/6)
|  |  +- 3VSB           :    3.344    3.344    3.344 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/7)
|  |  +- VBAT           :     3.28     3.28     3.28 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/8)
|  |  +- CPU            :       68       68     78.5 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/temperature/0)
|  |  +- Auxiliary      :       -1       -1       -1 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/temperature/1)
|  |  +- System         :       26       26       26 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/temperature/2)
|
+- Intel Pentium D 3.40GHz (/intelcpu/0)
|  +- Bus Speed      :  199.477  199.477  199.477 (/intelcpu/0/clock/0)
|  +- CPU Core #1    :   3391.1  2393.72   3391.1 (/intelcpu/0/clock/1)
|  +- CPU Core #2    :   3391.1  2393.72   3391.1 (/intelcpu/0/clock/2)
|  +- CPU Total      :  45.3125  44.5313  90.9091 (/intelcpu/0/load/0)
|  +- CPU Core #1    :  45.3125  45.3125      100 (/intelcpu/0/load/1)
|  +- CPU Core #2    :  45.3125  39.0625  90.3409 (/intelcpu/0/load/2)
|
+- Generic Memory (/ram)
|  +- Memory         :  43.4771  43.3971   43.516 (/ram/load/0)
|  +- Used Memory    :  1.72438  1.72121  1.72592 (/ram/data/0)
|  +- Available Memory :   2.2418  2.24026  2.24497 (/ram/data/1)
|
+- ST3500630NS (/hdd/0)
|  +- Temperature    :       51       51       51 (/hdd/0/temperature/0)
|  +- Used Space     :  49.5482  49.5482  49.5482 (/hdd/0/load/0)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parameters

|
+- Guso G4x 775 + ICH6 Series (/mainboard)
|  |
|  +- Winbond W83627DHG-P (/lpc/w83627dhgp)
|  |  |
|  |  +- CPU VCore (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/0)
|  |  |  +- Ri [kΩ] : 0 : 0
|  |  |  +- Rf [kΩ] : 1 : 1
|  |  |  +- Vf [V] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- Voltage #2 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/1)
|  |  |  +- Ri [kΩ] : 0 : 0
|  |  |  +- Rf [kΩ] : 1 : 1
|  |  |  +- Vf [V] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- AVCC (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/2)
|  |  |  +- Ri [kΩ] : 34 : 34
|  |  |  +- Rf [kΩ] : 34 : 34
|  |  |  +- Vf [V] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- 3VCC (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/3)
|  |  |  +- Ri [kΩ] : 34 : 34
|  |  |  +- Rf [kΩ] : 34 : 34
|  |  |  +- Vf [V] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- Voltage #5 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/4)
|  |  |  +- Ri [kΩ] : 0 : 0
|  |  |  +- Rf [kΩ] : 1 : 1
|  |  |  +- Vf [V] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- Voltage #6 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/5)
|  |  |  +- Ri [kΩ] : 0 : 0
|  |  |  +- Rf [kΩ] : 1 : 1
|  |  |  +- Vf [V] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- Voltage #7 (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/6)
|  |  |  +- Ri [kΩ] : 0 : 0
|  |  |  +- Rf [kΩ] : 1 : 1
|  |  |  +- Vf [V] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- 3VSB (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/7)
|  |  |  +- Ri [kΩ] : 34 : 34
|  |  |  +- Rf [kΩ] : 34 : 34
|  |  |  +- Vf [V] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- VBAT (/lpc/w83627dhgp/voltage/8)
|  |  |  +- Ri [kΩ] : 34 : 34
|  |  |  +- Rf [kΩ] : 34 : 34
|  |  |  +- Vf [V] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- CPU (/lpc/w83627dhgp/temperature/0)
|  |  |  +- Offset [°C] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- Auxiliary (/lpc/w83627dhgp/temperature/1)
|  |  |  +- Offset [°C] : 0 : 0
|  |  |
|  |  +- System (/lpc/w83627dhgp/temperature/2)
|  |  |  +- Offset [°C] : 0 : 0
|
+- Intel Pentium D 3.40GHz (/intelcpu/0)
|
+- Generic Memory (/ram)
|
+- ST3500630NS (/hdd/0)
|  |
|  +- Temperature (/hdd/0/temperature/0)
|  |  +- Offset [°C] : 0 : 0

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Mainboard

SMBIOS Version: 2.6

BIOS Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
BIOS Version: G41S610F

System Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
System Name: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
System Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Mainboard Manufacturer: LORD ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD.LORD
Mainboard Name: Guso G4x 775 + ICH6 Series
Mainboard Version: V1.0

Processor Manufacturer: Intel
Processor Version: Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.40GHz
Processor Core Count: 2
Processor Core Enabled: 2
Processor Thread Count: 2
Processor External Clock: 200 Mhz

Memory Device [0] Manufacturer: Manufacturer00
Memory Device [0] Part Number: ModulePartNumber00
Memory Device [0] Device Locator: DIMM0
Memory Device [0] Bank Locator: BANK0
Memory Device [0] Speed: 800 MHz

Memory Device [1] Manufacturer: Manufacturer01
Memory Device [1] Part Number: ModulePartNumber01
Memory Device [1] Device Locator: DIMM1
Memory Device [1] Bank Locator: BANK1
Memory Device [1] Speed: 0 MHz

Memory Device [2] Manufacturer: Manufacturer02
Memory Device [2] Part Number: ModulePartNumber02
Memory Device [2] Device Locator: DIMM2
Memory Device [2] Bank Locator: BANK2
Memory Device [2] Speed: 800 MHz

Memory Device [3] Manufacturer: Manufacturer03
Memory Device [3] Part Number: ModulePartNumber03
Memory Device [3] Device Locator: DIMM3
Memory Device [3] Bank Locator: BANK3
Memory Device [3] Speed: 0 MHz
```

---

```
CPUID

Processor 0

Processor Vendor: Intel
Processor Brand: Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.40GHz
Family: 0xF
Model: 0x6
Stepping: 0x5
```

---

```
GenericHarddisk

Drive name: ST3500630NS
Firmware version: 3CNR

Logical drive name: C:\
Format: NTFS
Total size: 62915133440
Total free space: 51727884288

Logical drive name: D:\
Format: NTFS
Total size: 73402363904
Total free space: 34005336064

Logical drive name: E:\
Format: NTFS
Total size: 83889594368
Total free space: 56561586176

Logical drive name: F:\
Format: NTFS
Total size: 279889793024
Total free space: 110013009920
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your question so its readable.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.  You seem to want to change something, but what?  From what, to what?  Why?  Lots of technical detail is nice, but out saying what, and why nobody can help you.

Comment: One of the worst posts I've seen since I started on SU. You have an issue with your BIOS? but you can provide this report? A simple **Intel Pentium D 3.40GHz** would suffice, we don't need all the excessive specs for each DIMM slot, core, HDD, and sensors (seriously?). What have you tried? What's your question? What are your symptoms?

Comment: my problem is the system is always burned due to temperature. I don't know how to ask question

Comment: Please take few moments to format your question correctly. There's a preview window so that you can *at least* take a look how your question will look like. Also your question title is _it is good or bad configuration_, while your body is about something completely different. There really is no way to answer this properly without you [edit]ing it and mentioning what exactly your question is

Answer (score 3):

Your program output is pretty difficult to read as it is not properly formatted, but assuming `68 68 78.5` are your CPU core temperatures, that's definitely pretty high (especially if this is idle temperature).

The main culprit I would check would be the heatsink - make sure it is seated securely and that it is free of dust. If it is dirty, remove it and clean with compressed air. Then, apply fresh [thermal paste](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=thermal%20paste&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Athermal%20paste) and put the heatsink back on.

Then, install the program [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) to monitor your CPU temps. Acceptable temperature will vary depending on CPU but for the Pentium D, I'd say aim to get it below 50 C idle and below 70 C under load.

If none of that worked, I would look into getting a [new heatsink and fan assembly](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=cpu%20heatsink%20pentium%20d&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Acpu%20heatsink%20pentium%20d).